# Iterating over two lists A and B

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to iterate over two lists A and B. Where the B is equal to A - A[i], where i = 1:

> For E.g. listA = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'].
>   For first Item, 'A' in List A, I
>   want the List B to have ['B', 'C', 'D'] For second Item 'B' in List A,
>   I want the List B to have ['A', 'C', 'D']

What I have tried until now.

```
listA = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
for term in listA:       
    listA.remove(term)
    for item in listA:
        print(listA)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `i = 0`?

Comment: So, you need multiple lists or just print them? Also do not remove element from list while iteration over it

Comment: Does the order of items in resulting sublists matter?

Comment: @kuro, print is just a placeholder for the function that goes there. The function would use both 'item' and 'term' i.e. function(item, term)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
>>> la = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
>>> for i in la:
    _temp = la.copy()
    _temp.remove(i)
    print(_temp)
```

---

**Output:**

```
['B', 'C', 'D']
['A', 'C', 'D']
['A', 'B', 'D']
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

<sub>*If you want to assign the print output to new variables, use a dictionary where the key will the name of list and value is printted output.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to print the sublists, it will be like:

```
 for i in range(len(listA)):
    print(listA[:i]+listA[i+1:])
```

Or,

```
for i in listA:
    print(list(set(listA) - set(i)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```py
listA = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

Bs = \
[listA[:idx] + listA[idx + 1:] 
    for idx 
    in range(len(listA))]

for B in Bs:
 print(B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking the above solutions a step further, you can store a reference to each of the resulting list in the corresponding variable using a dictionary comprehension:

```py
keys_map = {x: [item for item in listA if item != x] for x in listA}

print(keys_map)
```

---

#### Output

```py
{
 'A': ['B', 'C', 'D'],
 'B': ['A', 'C', 'D'],
 'C': ['A', 'B', 'D'],
 'D': ['A', 'B', 'C']
}
```

and access the desired key like so

```py
keys_map.get('A')

# returns

['B', 'C', 'D']
```